# Show a div on scroll of another div when this div is on top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two lists, One with further div of text and and other with further div images, each text match a specific picture. They are link with a data attribute.

What I want is - when you scroll, it show the image that correspond to the text (that have the same data attribute) . And it has to change every-time that a text arrived of the top of the div that scroll. I want to do this in Jquery or Js.

```
<ul id="mylist" class="mylist">
    <li data-myId="465" class="mydiv">
        <h2>My tittle</h2>
        <p>texte></p>
    </li>
    <li data-myId="466" class="mydiv">
        <h2>My tittle</h2>
        <p>texte</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="mylist" class=« mylist ">
    <li data-myId="465 "  class="news-work ">
    <img>
    </li>
    <ul id="mylist " class=« mylist">
    <li data-myId="465" class="news-work">
        <img>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not put the text and the image in the same list and style it properly with CSS?

Comment: I can't change the HTML, if I could would do it in Css